# Рывки страницы при прокрутке к якорю

Tags: javascript

Привет. Есть горизонтальное меню, которое прокручивается вместе с страницей вниз. При переходе к якорю заголовок страницы находится под меню. Добавил отступ - 90. Теперь при нажатии на кнопку заголовок сперва прячется под меню, а затем его выталкивает назад. Можно ли как то сделать, чтобы страница стразу тормозила в нужном месте? Еще заметил, что при 2-ом нажатии на кнопку некоторые якори отматываются сильней назад.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 /*handles scroll animation*/
 $(function() {
   $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
    if (target.length) {
   $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: target.offset().top - 90
   }, 400);
   return false;
    }
  }
   });
 });

 /*makes nav detachable*/
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height() - 25;
 var scrolled = false;
 
 $(window).scroll(function() { 
 fixedNav();
 }); 
 
 var fixedNav = function(){
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
     
  if (scrollTop > viewportHeight) { 
   $('#staticNav').addClass('fixed');
   scrolled = true;
  } else if (scrolled == true && scrollTop < viewportHeight) {  
   $('#staticNav').removeClass('fixed');
   $('#staticNav').addClass('unfixed');
   setTimeout(function () {
    scrolled = false;
    }, 300);
   if (scrollTop < 200){
    $('#staticNav').removeClass('unfixed');
   }
  } else {
   $('#staticNav').removeClass('unfixed');
   $('#staticNav').removeClass('fixed');
  }
  
 };
});
```

Comment: Дело может быть в том, что сначала срабатывает стандартное поведение браузера (переход к якорю). А потом запускается скрипт. Для того что бы оставить только скрипт, нужно запретить браузеру обрабатывать клик на эту ссылку. Для этого нужно выполнить `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Скажите, пожалуйста, а куда именно в мой код нужно это поставить, чтобы заработало? За пример буду особенно признателен и позже отпишу получилось или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Пример того, как работает обрабочик события и стандартная обработка браузера. Первая ссылка **не** блокирует обработку клика браузером. Вторая блокирует при помощи `event.preventDefault()`

```js
var $linkA = document.querySelector('#link-a'),
    $linkB = document.querySelector('#link-b');

$linkA.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  alert('Поведение обработчика');
});

$linkB.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('Поведение обработчика');
});
```

```html
<a id="link-a" href="javascript:alert('Поведение браузера по умолчанию, при клике на ссылку');">Поведение браузера + обработчик</a>

<br>

<a id="link-b" href="javascript:alert('Поведение браузера по умолчанию, при клике на ссылку');">Только обработчик</a>
```

Что касается вашего примера, блокировку события нужно добавить вместо `return false;`